# share in-app purchase on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

Am I allowed to share in-app purchases across ios and android?

I would have a free multiplayer game that is on android and ios.

The user could purchase a digital item with the in-app billing api in his android app. I would verify the purchase on the game server and add the item to his online account. When the user opens the ios app and logs into his account, he would stil have the item since its saved on the server.

This would also be done in reverse.

Does the android or ios policy allow this? Or must digital goods purchased on one platform only be available there?

I have already seen games that do this but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 11 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) details the rules of in-app purchases. The short answer is **no**, you can not share in-app purchases between Android and iOS.

Comment: I both check out Section 11 in the old guidelines and Section 3 in the new guidelines and I can not see anything regarding OS- or Device restrictions. All I can find is "Must be used in the App" - but to me, that does not sound that it is restricted to platform.

Comment: Why not? If it's tied to an online account how Apple knows it's being used on other platforms? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Better answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200085/in-app-purchases-share-user-in-app-purchases-between-android-and-ios

Short answer: YES.