# uwp app - how use subscription?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, in-app-billing

I created my app for three platforms - android, uwp app (for desktop) and Windows Phone. I want to use the monetization model -  subscription. But UWP not supported 
subscription model now. I found only the message that this feature is in the [plans](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2017/B8098).  But I do not have time to wait.
  I see the only possibility - to use consumed purchases and most control business logic in the application. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see the only possibility - to use consumed purchases and most control business logic in the application.

Currently, the [durable add-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-purchases-of-apps-and-add-ons) can be an option for you. Please note that the durable add-ons can be purchased only once. They are not consumed, but you could set the `Product Lifetime` so customer can purchase them again after it expires.

For the purpose of subscription, you could remind users whether they want to renew it when the add-on expires. You can custom the UI of this part. When user click "renew" button, just invoke `RequestPurchaseAsync` method to complete the purchase.

> Any other ideas?

According to [Store Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx), you can only use Windows Store Purchase API to sell digital items or services within your app. However, the method for subscription add-on is not available to most developer accounts currently. But according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662769/windows-store-app-in-app-purchase-subscription-model), the feature will be "available to all developers later this summer". Since you don't have time to wait, you may try the workaround firstly for the time being.

Comment: Thank you. I try durable add-on.