# How can I use stripe as periodic subscription within Swift iOS app for user to access specific content?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am building an iOS app with swift 4 and I'm trying to use the stripe paid monthly subscription for users to pay periodically in order to access the content within the app, and if they cancel subscriptions they will no longer be able to access content within the app (firebase is used for authentication and all data)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase), this is not allowed. You *must* use Apple's in-app purchase system for in-app subscriptions. To read more about it, you can see [Apple's page for it on their developer site](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Comment: What if I want to have the app both for iOS and Android, if I use apple in app purchase if user login using android, the membership will not be available then since android does not connect to apple in app purchase

Comment: Regardless, Apple makes you use `StoreKit`/their in-app purchase system on iOS. If you want to share purchases across platforms, you're responsible for keeping track of who bought what and syncing that to their other devices. Here's an answer to another question with more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127641/2895075

Comment: I got it,Thanks you!