# Can iOS and Android share the in-app currency or subscription across platform?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I understand I could make it share across platform.
However in one of my project right now, our customer has requirement to make the user purchased in-app currency to not be able to share across platform.

Our customer said that is a policy from Apple. I haven't heard about this nor I can   find such documentation.

I don't have such deep knowledge with Apple development or Android development, is there such policy exists?

(I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960841/share-in-app-purchase-on-ios-and-android), someone answered no cannot be shared, but comment in the thread also said cannot find such guide line.)